# I want to ask about the difference betweeen "Grab Someone by the Arm" and "Grab Someone's Arm"

Tags: complementation

I'm learning English as my second language, and what one of my college teacher explained seems not quiet right.

He said that these words, such as 'grab, pull, etc', whenever they are used, it has to be like this:

> He grabbed her by the arm, or He took him by the collar.

Not like:

> He grabbed her arm, or He took his collar.

He said the person that comes after the verb always has to be objective, never possessive, and preposition has to follow them.

I've already googled these words and saw many usages like:

> 'My boyfriend grabbed my arm.Is that abuse?'

I know saying like 'he grab her on the arm' is not wrong, but is it wrong to say or write 'he grab her arm'?

Answer (score 6):

> He grabbed her by the arm.
>
> He grabbed her arm.

Both sentences are correct. The difference can be illustrated by context.

1. He grabbed her by the arm and started to pull her towards the door. [He is performing an action on *her* and he uses her arm as a way to do it.]
2. He grabbed her arm so that he could see what was  tattooed  on it. [He is performing an action specifically on her *arm* -- not on her whole person.]

---

> He took him by the collar.
>
> He took his collar.

3. The teacher took the misbehaving student by the collar and escorted him out of the classroom. [He used the collar as a means to move the pupil.]
4. He took his collar.  [This perhaps refers to a removable collar such as is found on a dress suit. Someone took/removed/perhaps even stole the collar.]

Comment: neatly explained +1 for the content above the line. Also, in the first example, grabbing her by 'the' arm and 'her' arm may also make the difference depending on the context.

Comment: @MaulikV - Yes, context is vital in English. I simplified my answer and it would be possible to change the meaning of the phrases by deliberately choosing a different  context for them. I decided not to go into the ramifications so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, except that it should be, "He pulled her by **the** arm."  Note that 'the arm' refers to her arm not his arm.  If you said, "He pulled her by arm." it would mean that he used *his* arm to pull her, so that is a third meaning!

Comment: Ah, I see. Those articles are very confusing, anyway thanks again.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately articles are quite difficult to learn for non-native speakers. However they can make a big difference to the meaning.

Comment: Many European languages prefer reflexives to body-locus objects in some situations; in German, one washes oneself the face, for instance. English doesn't worry about this nicety, but it does provides distancing constructions for those who miss reflexives. Either is correct, and there is no meaning difference, as is normally the case when there are two ways to say something in English.